# NServiceBus & IoT - place a message from client directly in queue and process with NServiceBus at server side

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus5

Out back-end is written in .NET using NServiceBus (version 5). Until now, our clients (both .NET clients and c++ clients) were sending messages to a WCF service that has NServiceBus, and the WCF service send the NServiceBus message to the right worker.

Right now we are doing some changes to our architecture and would like some clients to put messages directly in queue and skip the WCF. We have many devices (most are written in c++).

I know that NServiceBus wraps the messages it puts in queue with it's own object. My question is if there is any way for NServiceBus to work in IoT environments - where devices are putting messages directly in to queue, without an adapter in the middle? or for the server side (worker) to handle "regular" messages not wrapped with the NServiceBus object?

Comment: what transport r u using?

Comment: @Simon we are now redesigning our architecture. currently it's msmq but we are moving to either RabbitMQ or Azure ServiceBus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what's your Transport, if you're trying to just Send a message to a destination or Publish an event? Some of these choices might change the answer here, but you should get a gist of it.

You *can* integrate with NServiceBus directly by putting messages into the queue. If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus) you'll see there is 'Scripting' section under each transport which shows you how to put messages directly into the queue. If you want to integrate with MSMQ you can find the documentation page [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/msmq/operations-scripting).

NSB messages come with [Headers](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/message-headers). Most of the values in the header is optional and they come with a sensible default values so all you really need is the message type (the actual type name for the message payload). Assuming you want to do a Send, you can see *all* the headers that's at play [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/message-headers). Again you don't need all of that.

To answer your question: To integrate with NSB from your C++ code, you can translate this C# code to C++ and that's all you need:

```
public static void SendMessage(string queuePath, string messageBody, List<HeaderInfo> headers)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (var queue = new MessageQueue(queuePath))
        using (Message message = new Message())
        {
            message.BodyStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
            message.Extension = CreateHeaders(headers);
            queue.Send(message, MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
        }
        scope.Complete();
    }
}

public static byte[] CreateHeaders(List<HeaderInfo> headerInfos)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<HeaderInfo>));
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, headerInfos);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}

public class HeaderInfo
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Things to note:

- MSMQ works with TransactionScope. I don't think on IoT that's an option depending on the device you use.
- You still need a library to put a message into MSMQ.

If you've chosen SQL transport, it'd have made this integration much easier as all you had to do was to write a record in the db (which you can also find a script for [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sqlserver/operations-scripting)).

Answer (score 0):

No one will ever guarantee the transport message format. I would advise you to keep away from the idea of queueing messages and expect NServiceBus to consume them directly.

Instead, have messages from devices to be received by a broke, which will re-send them to NServiceBus as needed. Hence that devices usually emit optimised messages that, for example, fit to a smallest number of TCP frames possible. NServiceBus does not care about this. Check transport messages with Json and XML serializers - they are huge.

I use AQMP for message exchange between my event hub and devices. Then, at the event hub, I can do what I want, including using NServiceBus. Consider what the industry suggests for devices. AQMP is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Alexey,
Isn't what you are suggesting will add another hop for each message. If this is the case why not just have a HTTP call from the IoT device to the cloud. The HTTP handler will just put it in the queue using NServiceBus client side library. By using the HTTP handler I will have a better option to change the inner implementation (hence the queue) in the future.

Comment: It does but everyone who really works with devices would tell you that when you have millions of messages per second, you cannot afford having kilobytes of crap in your message and XML overhead is considered as unnecessary crap. Reliably consolidating messages and bringing them to a processing engine is a separate task. This is, for example, what Azure EventHub is used for.